# How to check whether a CGPoint is inside UIImageView multiple times dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, touch

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, so if I'm being a complete noob please give me a direction to go in on this.

My issue is that I have user uploaded images that are displayed in a list that they can click on to execute an action to modify/delete. The below way is a very tedious way to program it but I can't seem to think of a way to dynamically do this without reworking the image handling completely...

```
- (void)tapImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:imageView.superview];

    if (point.y > 35 && point.y < 135)
        imageIndexInteger = 0;

    else if (point.y > 168 && point.y < 268)
        imageIndexInteger = 1;

    else if (point.y > 301 && point.y < 401)
        imageIndexInteger = 2;
    //need to figure out how to do this dynamically for more than 3 images
}
```

I have an array that is storing the uploaded images (call it imageArray for this example)

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you displaying the imageviews? adding them to subviews? 
It will be better to use UICollectionView/UITableView for listing the image views and use their datasource and delegate methods for catching the tap

Comment: @Nithin is right.

But i would suggest you should go with UITableView which will be relatively easy for you to implement, since you are new to obj-c. Also, to get different tap as you doing above. Try making custom UITableViewCell class having button with their selectors, instead of calculating the taps as above.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to accomplish this is very roundabout.

The best solution to this would probably be to use a `UICollectionView` or a `UITableView` and handle the touches as cell selections, then you can just get the index of the cell.

If you want to keep your code the way it is now, the quickest hack to do this would be to assign a tag to each image view like this:

```
myImageView.tag = 5;
```

Then you can get the tag like this:

```
- (void)tapImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    imageIndexInteger = imageView.tag;
}
```

Comment: The quick hack provided worked well. When I have the time I will do a change to UITableView but since I'm editing code created by another person for this part it would require a long time. Thanks @Dima